# Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains - While Search Tag

Tags: python, django, django-views, tags

I am building a BlogApp and I am trying to implement a search field which will search ( filter ) with entered `tag`.

When i try to access the page then it is keep showing

> Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30,default='')
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

views.py

```
from taggit.models import Tag

def search_page(request):
    query = request.GET.get('p')
    object_list = BlogPost.objects.filter(tags__icontains=query)

    context = {'posts': object_list, 'query': query}
    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

I have also tried different methods but still showing the same error.

- I tried `.filter(tags__in=query)` then it showed

> NoneType' object is not iterable

- The i tried `Tag.objects.filter(question__tags__icontains=query)` then it showed

> Related Field got invalid lookup: icontains

Any help would be much Appreciated. Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify that you are looking to the *name* of the tag, so:

```
object_list = BlogPost.objects.filter(tags__name__icontains=query)
```

You should filter only if there is a query, so:

```
from taggit.models import Tag

def search_page(request):
    query = request.GET.get('p')
    object_list = BlogPost.objects.all()
    if query is not None:
        object_list = object_list.filter(tags__icontains=query)
    context = {'posts': object_list, 'query': query}
    return render(request, 'search.html', context)
```

likely you also want to use `q` instead of <s>`p`</s> for the query parameter name.

Comment: Thanks BUT now it saying `Cannot use None as a query value`

Comment: @Van: you should only filter in case `query` is not `None`, if it is `None` (in this case if you do not filter with `?p=...`, then it can of course not filter on a non-existing `query`.

Comment: @Van: likely you want to use `'q'` instead of `p`, and thus query with `/?q=tagname`.

Comment: When i type tag **first , second** ( they are two different tags ) than it is not searching `two posts` at the same time.